# Saving money as a group but source is shady

Tags: halal-haram, money

In asia countires, People have kamati/kaymati (sound : committee), in which everyone put in certain amount for certain time of period and every month, each member get money. There is someone who has shady business (to what I know is they avoided huge tax on imports).

My question is, because each month a member get total amount of money collected from each member, with that member included in it and her source of income was avoidance of tax or selling drugs, does it make the member who took thier turn haram money?

Comment: Interesting question! I heard about such a regulation elsewhere too. If I have well understood it is like this:Let's say 4 friends agree to have a common collection of money each person must join in with a fixed amount let's say 50$ each, but one of them has the whole money (200$) and can spend it as he wants during the time, in the next month the whole amount (200$) should move to the second etc. after 4 months each of these friends would have access to the fully saved amount of money. Is it like that?

Comment: I've read an article in which two fatwas were presented one considering this as a kind of credit without due date (because in this case the person who may hold in hand the whole amount is chosen by lot) and that is against the qur'an [2:282](https://legacy.quran.com/2/282) (no specified term), another scholar says no it isn't a credit, but a kind of saving.

Comment: @Medi1Saif regarding the example u mention. yes and no. after 4 months the "kamati" would end because that one person is saving so e.g.say all friends have decided that each month which will get the money, so Month is Adam, Month 2 is Bilal, Month 3 is jon, Month 4 is Osman, so Month 1 Adam will get 50$ * 4 = 200$ (now adam won't get any payment but will still pay for rest of 3 months),  Month 2 Bilal will get 200$ collected by 4 members (he won't be paid but will put in 50$ for next 2 months) and so on.